# RegEx to match a number in the second line

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to match a number in the second line. Similar input is like this:

```
^C1.1
xC20 
SS3 
M 4
```

Decimal pattern `(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)` matches all numbers and second number can be get in a loop on the code behind but I need a regular expression to get directly the number in the second line.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, it is C#

Comment: Also, is the number you're looking for always on the second line?

Comment: Try this:- /^[^\r\n]*\r?\n\D*(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)/

Comment: sometimes 3 or more, but it sometimes comes only 2 lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^[^\r\n]*\r?\n\D*?(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)/
```

This operates by capturing a single line at the beginning of the input:

```
^         Beginning of the string
[^\r\n]*  Anything that isn't a line terminator
\r?\n     A newline, optionally preceded by a carriage return
```

Then  all the non digit characters, then your numbers.

Since you've now repeatedly changed your needs, try this on for size:

```
/(?<=\n\D*)-?\d+(\.\d+)?/
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but it is getting more than second line number

Comment: I used a lookbehind.  It's a ridiculously more expensive way to accomplish what you're looking for - but it'll match **just the number**.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to capture it with this regex.

```
.*\n\D*(\d*).*\n
```

Comment: The leading `.*` is kind of unnecessary.  As is the trailing `.*\n`.

Comment: it is matching with first two lines, i only need second line number

Comment: \n\D*(\d*).*\n this is works for only second line but gets all line, not only number :(

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan Thanks for your tips. I'm relatively new to regex.

Comment: @ihsany didn't see that you were using C# until after I had posted. Sorry about that. Mine seems to work in [Pythex](http://pythex.org/).

Comment: @raddevon It's an otherwise very clever regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Check out group 1 of anything that this matches:

```
^.*?\r\n.*?(\d+)
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
^.*?\r\n.*?(\d+)
```

Both are with multiline NOT set...

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the captured group in `/^.*?\r?\n.*?(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/` where…

```
^                  # beginning of string
.*?                # anything...
\r?\n              # followed by a new line
.*?                # anything...
(                  # followed by...
   -?              # an optional negative sign (minus)
   \d+             # a number
   (?:             #   -this part not captured explicitly-
       \.\d+       # a dot and a number
   )?              #   -and is optional-
)
```

If it is a flavor that supports lookbehind then there are other alternatives.